# Run an R function in parallel / using furr / Syntax

Tags: r, igraph, furrr

I have this call on igraph object (gr_muc) that changes the weights of the vertices.

```
E(gr_muc)[edges_from]$weight <- E(gr_muc)[edges_from]$weight * 2
E(gr_muc)[edges_to]$weight <- E(gr_muc)[edges_to]$weight * 2
```

Is it possible to use `furrr` or some other means to run those calls on multiple cores?
How would such call look like?
Thank you in advance!
BR.

Comment: to take advantage of `furrr`, you first have to find a way to partition the data in smaller chunks and process these chunks in sub-tasks, see [this explanation](https://psu-psychology.github.io/r-bootcamp-2018/talks/parallel_r.html). Do you see a way to partition the igraph object you're processing?

Comment: have to think about it. But is it not already split in at least 2 tasks? 1. edges_from and 2. edges_to? Could not those 2 tasks run in parrallel ?

Comment: I'm afraid not, because both assignements share the same object `E(gr_muc)`